# Does anyone know of a jQuery magnification plugin for embedded pdf objects?

Tags: jquery, pdf, object, zooming, magnify

So far all the zoom of magnifying plugins I have found are for images and I need something that will work when hovered over an embedded object tag .pdf file.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically images can be rendered properly from the browser and can be "embedded" into a web page, while the PDF cannot be embedded directly into html, and that's why they cannot be zoomed.

You cannot see a PDF preview in a page. Well, it's possible, but not with pure JavaScript. You can embed the file in a web page using something like this: https://docs.google.com/viewer

here is an example: http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/viewer/examples/book-animate.html

but I don't believe it's possible to achieve the effect you like.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use Flash. You can use something like Scribd, and use the embed code on your site. Or make your own flash-based PDF Reader.

Another way to do this would be to convert the PDF file into a series of images (On Acrobat, use File->Export->Image). Then, you can use one of those magnification plugins in conjunction with all the images. If your PDF file is really long, you can use jQuery to automatically load the images as the page loads (similar to how the new Google Images has endless scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

Along with Scribd and making your own Flash application to read this, you could also use something like the program Adobe Captivate, which takes all manner of files and creates Flash presentations out of them.

Scribd is probably the easiest. Google Docs Viewer has great support too, but the Scribd viewer is just.. tidier.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess you are looking for preview kind of thing, then I would say there's no point in it, coz embedded pdf in whatever (iframe/object) will download the whole PDF anyway before any preview magic on hover or something else.

But if you really want to play with some good plugin that handle pdf rendering with some good effects, then have a look at [JQuery Media Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/media/misc.html).